# BIND returns SERVFAIL after setting seemingly correct records

Tags: networking, dns, bind

EDIT: UPDATED CODE

I used nslookup ercont.club 127.0.0.1 to make sure that it would be using my host name server and that it wouldn't be something to do with my registrar. Here are the files:

db.ercont.club

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
    $TTL    604800
    @       IN      SOA     ercont.club. mail.ercont.club. (
                              4         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers - NS records
@        IN      NS      ns1.ercont.club.
@        IN      NS      ns2.ercont.club.

; name servers - A records
ns1.ercont.club.        IN      A       167.160.84.198
ns2.ercont.club.        IN      A       167.160.84.198

; - A records
ercont.club             IN      A       167.160.84.198
```

/etc/bind/zones/db.160.67

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ercont.club. mail.ercont.club. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers
@        IN      NS      ns1.ercont.club.
@        IN      NS      ns2.ercont.club.

; PTR Records
198.84     IN      PTR     ns1.ercont.club.        ;
198.84     IN      PTR     ns2.ercont.club.        ;
198.84     IN      PTR     mail.ercont.club.       ;
```

and /etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
acl "trusted" {
        167.160.84.198; # ns1 and ns2
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { localhost; trusted; };
        allow-query { localhost; 167.160.84.0/8; };
        listen-on { 167.160.84.198; };
        allow-transfer { none; };

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };

        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

If someone could help me troubleshoot this, that would be really nice of you. I'm a noob at bind and the issues really freak me out, so some help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, a public dns server, such as the Registar, where the domain name was purchased, will need to be setup to point your TCP/IP Address, example server or residential gateway public IP address. This may also be completed through a third party service such as route53 through aws.amazon.com service.

This answer though is to cover the topic of resolving the domain name(ercont.club) from the local/private machine that has Bind9 installed.

The file: `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` resembles the following, and appears to be correct.

```
acl "trusted" {
        167.160.84.198; # ns1 and ns2
};
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { localhost; trusted; };
        allow-query { localhost; 167.160.84.0/8; };
        listen-on { 167.160.84.198; };
        allow-transfer { none; };
forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
dnssec-validation auto;
auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

The File: `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` should resemble the following:

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";

view "internal" {
        match-clients {
                localhost;
                167.160.84.0/8;
        };
# set zone 
        zone "ercont.club" {
                type master;
                file "/etc/bind/db.ercont.club";
                allow-update { none; };
        };
# set reverse zone lookup
        zone "160.67.in-addr.arpa" {
                type master;
                file "/etc/bind/db.160.67";
                allow-update { none; };
        };
        include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
};
```

The file: `db.ercont.club`

```
; BIND data file for local loopback interface 
; 
$TTL 604800 
@ IN SOA ercont.club. mail.ercont.club. ( 
         3      ; Serial 
    604800      ; Refresh 
    86400       ; Retry 
    2419200     ; Expire 
    604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL 
; name servers - NS records 
@    IN     NS    ns1.ercont.club. 
@    IN     NS    ns2.ercont.club.
@    IN     A       127.0.0.1
@    IN     A       167.160.84.198


; A records 
ercont.club.      A       167.160.84.198
```

Prior to saving the file, increment the serial number by at least 1.

Issue command: `sudo named-checkzone ercont.club db.ercont.club`

If Zone OK, continue. If not review and correct.

The file: `/etc/bind/db.167.160`:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ercont.club. mail.ercont.club. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers
@        IN      NS      ns1.ercont.club.
@        IN      NS      ns2.ercont.club.
; PTR Records
198.84     IN      PTR     ns1.ercont.club.        ;
198.84     IN      PTR     ns2.ercont.club.        ;
198.84     IN      PTR     mail.ercont.club.       ;
```

Prior to saving the file, increment the serial number by at least 1.
Issue command: `sudo named-checkzone 167.160.in-addr.arpa db.167.160`

If Zone OK, continue. If not review and correct.

Issue Command: `sudo service bind9 restart`

Verify the service started properly, issue the command: `sudo service bind9 status`

Before it will translate accordingly, we need to setup the server to point to the new DNS Server.
If this is a server only setup, no desktop client; we will want to review the file: `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 167.160.84.198
        netmask 255.0.0.0
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        dns-nameservers 167.160.84.198
        dns-search ercont.club
```

Otherwise, if you a Desktop and NetWork Manger, make the changes via the gui interface, or modify the file:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired\ connection\ 1
```

Changing the Wired\ connection\ 1, for what appears in Network Manager as the name of the connection.

Find the [ipv4] section of the file and add/modify the following two lines:

```
[ipv4]
dns=ipofyourdnsserver;
dns-search=ercont.club;
```

Save your modifications, and restart.

I hope this helps.

Comment: BIND still returns servfail after doing "nslookup ercont.club"

Comment: output: `Default server: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Default server: 167.160.84.198
Address: 167.160.84.198#53
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53`

Comment: for ns1 NXDOMAIN, and for ns1.ercont.club SERVFAIL

Comment: Could you perform this and post your results? `sudo named-checkzone ercont.club db.ercont.club`, additionally are you performing the nslookup on the same host with bind9 installed, or a different one?

Comment: This comes from [aws.amazon.com post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=737142&tstart=0)....   Though essentially, To fix your issue you need to update name servers in the company that hosts your domain name, i.e. Amazon Registrar, Inc. Your should use name servers from the NS record in your hosted zone

Comment: i did update the nameservers in my registrar to point to my current ip. the 167.160.84.198

Comment: btu if the 127.0.0.1 lookup for ns1 returned an nxdomain then i think something is wrong with the configuration files? otherwise it would find the DNS record

Comment: `zone ercont.club/IN: loaded serial 4
OK`
for `sudo named-checkzone ercont.club db.ercont.club`

Comment: Could you edit your post, and append what the zone file, now looks like?

Comment: edited the files and also changed the name to db.167.160, think i messed up there based on digitalocean tutorial. still has the same errors

Comment: `; - A records
ercont.club             IN      A       167.160.84.198`  Change this line, to `ercont.club.    IN     A 167.160.84.198`     I really think you need to specify a host name in this section, modify that line, and update the serial number. do the `namd-checkzone` command again, and `sudo service bind9 restart'.

Comment: i hope youre still there. even after fixing that i get the same errors. starting to worry me a little bit

Comment: @JThom         I've edited my post, with the next steps related to the dns client side. Please let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @JThom            I did a rewrite of my answer, I hope this is clear and addresses the issue. Please let me know.